# 'Welcome back' on mobile shows at the bottom

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

Since pictures say it all:

> [image]

The 'Welcome back' image is shown at the bottom of the page, and in particular on the front page, it is a very long way to see that message.

Can we either:

- Let it away on mobile;
- Inline it under the header;
- Some other way to make it more visible?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1373/

Comment: @Doorknob冰: True. 19% is good enough though to make it to the day. :)

Comment: Good point dude!